# Visual Studio breakpoints only work on second debug attempt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, breakpoints

I have a VS 2010 solution with a web application project, and several class library projects to which the web app project has project references. When I am trying to debug the code for one of the class library projects through the F5 debug build process, the Modules window normally fails to load the symbols for the DLL in question, or if it does, the breakpoints are ignored anyway. However, on the second attempt at an F5 debug build, the breakpoints usually are recognized, and the code will halt in the required location.

I have tried ALL sorts to fix this issue - all the usual solution cleaning business, repeating the referencing procedure. I didn't see this issue until I upgraded to VS 2010, after which I rebuilt a new VS2010 solution from existing projects. I am beginning to think this is some sort of timing bug in 2010, as I am making no changes between the first and second attempt - it's as though VS 2010 is disregarding the dependendencies in the build configuration, and starting the web app build before the PDB for the class library is ready, or before it can locate the PDB for the class library.

Has anybody seen similar behaviour in VS2010? As you can imagine it is adding considerable amounts of 'productivity killing' time to my debugging, having to build everything 2 or 3 times just to get the breakpoints to be recognized.

Thanks if you can advise.

Comment: Perform clean solution and see if that helps.  I think it'll have similar effect as what omer schleifer is saying.

Answer (score 0):

Try erasing the bin and obj folders between runs. does it help?
I have similar issues with a web server which does not get changes made to the configuration file on VS2010.